# Return to Original Cell After Running Macro

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I had recorded a Macro and then put code in it to remember the active cell and then return me to that cell even after the function ran. The purpose of the `Set myActiveCell = ActiveCell` at the beginning of the code and `myActiveCell.Activate` was NOT to register that my active cell was A14 and then return me there after running my sort function, but to register that I am in A14 prior to the function and then to return me to that cell (no longer necessarily A14) after the function runs. What am I doing wrong and how do I make it work correctly?

```
Set myActiveCell = ActiveCell
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("K2:K600"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B600"), _SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("e2:e600")
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C600"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:zz600")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
    myActiveCell.Activate
End Sub
```

TIA

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a simple answer to that because the range object doesn't change with the sort. You'll have to search for the correct cell using whatever criteria are necessary to identify it. What you might do is tag the cell using its ID property, then loop and check the relevant column's cells after the sort.

Comment: What happens when you get to that line? It works for me (the `myActiveCell.Activate`). Does it not activate any cell? Does it activate the incorrect cell? Basically, what's not working? You can step through your macro with `F8` which can help pinpoint where the code goes awry.

Comment: Bruce, when I choose to sort my sheet by number (or any other criteria) and I select the cell that (after the new sort criteria) is now B11, after I run the macro, the active cell should be what is now (after the preferred sort macro) B216, however, the cursor/selected cell remains as B11 (now populated with different data - after running the macro). The weird thing is, the Macro used to work, but after I edited it manually (changing ranges from a2:ba546 to a2:ba600 to allow for more data input) the preferred sort no longer returned me to the required cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding a comment to the cell, then searching after sorting for the comment, like this:

```
Sub AddThenFindComment()

    Dim myActiveCell  As Range
    Set myActiveCell = Selection

    myActiveCell.AddComment "StartCell"

    'OTHER CODE

    Cells.Find(What:="StartCell", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlComments, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    Selection.ClearComments

End Sub
```

Comment: dendarii - thank you for this edit, works like a charm. However, now I need to be careful not to have a cell with an existing comment selected when running the macro. Love the workaround, but would definitely prefer to figure out why my Macro broke. Please see comment I left to @BruceWayne. My understanding of Macros is that the longer the code, the longer the process, so adding lines is really a backup/workaround, but still gets the job done. WOndering if there is a way to shorten/repair my code. Again, this is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Glad you found that useful, Rafi, and good point about checking the cell's comment before adding another. Consider accepting this answer in order to flag the question as answered.